# Magento 1.9 - How to get price format in javascript or jquery?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, price, jquery, format

I am trying to get magento price format in php file using jquery / javascript function but facing problem.

What I have tried ....

```
<script>
var price = 10;
var priceFormat = '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency("<script>document.write(price)</script>", true, false); ?>';
console.log(priceFormat); // output 0.00
</script>
```

However it should be 10.00

Is this right approach to get price format? If not then how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cookie is the better solution i think.

Just write your code:

```
`<script> document.cookie = "myJavascriptVar = " + myJavascriptVar </script>
<?php  $myPhpVar= $_COOKIE['myJavascriptVar'];?>

var priceFormat = '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($myPhpVar, true, false); ?>';
console.log(priceFormat); `
```

Sorry, posted from mobile. It works .

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is pass in a string to the core helper method, where it'll be expecting a numerical value.  It doesn't feel great but you could always pass in a defined number (e.g. 98.76) and then do a regex replace in JS for that number